# Unexpected email warning for Exceeding rate request

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I just received an email : Your app recently exceeded 75% of your plan's request limit of 30 requests/second. Additional requests to Parse exceeding the rate of 40 requests/second will be dropped, returning an error with error code 155.

But I haven't sent any push notification to any user then how it is possible that app exceeds request limit.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are only one type of request tracked by parse. You are probably making other request types. From the [Parse FAQ](https://parse.com/plans/faq) (emphasis added):

> **What is considered an API request?**
>
> Anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your app using
>   one of the Parse SDKs or REST API, it counts as an API request. ***This
>   does include things like queries, saves, logins, amongst other kinds
>   of requests.*** It also includes requests to send push notifications,
>   although this is seen as a single request regardless of how many
>   recipients are targeted. Serving Parse files counts as an API request,
>   including static assets served from Parse Hosting. Analytics requests
>   do have a special exemption. You can send us your analytics events any
>   time without being limited by your app's request limit.